# Unable to connect to VSTS LocalDB instance

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, localdb

We run integration tests in a Visual Studio Online build tasks, executing them against a LocalDB instance that runs on the hosted VSTS build agent.

We have a task to start LocalDB by executing these commands:

```
sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB
sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB
sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB
```

This seems OK when it runs:

```
LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" started.
Name:               MSSQLLocalDB
Version:            13.1.4001.0
Owner:              factoryvm-az442\VssAdministrator
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
```

The connection string from the integration test project look like this:

```
Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

This has been working for over a year now, but over the past few days we are seeing this when trying to run the tests:

```
Login failed for user 'factoryvm-az442\VssAdministrator'
```

Since `Trusted_Connection` is used, I'm not sure why it can't login. I did also try removing it. I also tried parsing the instance named pipe name from the output of `sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB` and using that in the connection string, e.g. `Server=np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#1579B709\tsql\query;Database=MyDatabase`, but then I get:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
```

Any idea how we can get this running again?

Note: Please note this is *not* the same as #[44724118](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724118/login-failure-for-vsts-localdb), as I do not have an invalid connection string and am not using `IntegratedSecurity`

Comment: This [MSDN SQL Server Question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e516ddff-8f1b-43d8-b3ba-1dccd68222f3/provider-named-pipe-provider-error-0-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe?forum=sqldatabaseengine) may provide some insight. It isn't quite the same problem, but in this case the error was caused by TCP/IP not being fully enabled or configured for the local DB to receive outside communication.

Comment: That's for an old version of SQL Server, rather than LocalDB. All the same, I have tried using named pipes too, but I got `No process is on the other end of the pipe`

Comment: @Cocowalla Can you run the command successfully through sqllocaldb utility locally?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Yes, everything still works when running locally. This was all working fine in VSTS until around a week ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/issues/194), and someone from Microsoft replied that they updated the VSTS agent image - this seems to have resolved the problem.